# Control Main Menu in another application

Tags: delphi, api, handles

I'm creating a component that will make access to other applications and fill informations to them. Usually call up forms of other applications and will automate the filling informations in fields. The class of filling is ready. I did all access through the windows Handles. It's working perfectly.

What do I need to do now is access the main menu of this other application and browse in menu items. With this, Its possible access any form in application.

I did several tests but without success. Could anyone give a hint?

Thankful now.

Comment: You wan't to *browse* the items, i.e. drop the menu and etc.. or call what an item calls? BTW, there's no point in mentioning that you've done tests unless you elaborate on what you've tried.

Comment: Much easier to use an automation interface. In the absence of that I recommend AutoHotKey.

Comment: Hi people. Sertac, my intention is access main menu in another app to call your windows to manipulate fields. The class to work with fields are ready. But, in my tests I could not access the main menu. Just missing this part, access the menu of another application.
To access the menu, I used the method GetMenu that returns a Handle HMenu. So far so good, the problem is through this menu and access the items.

Comment: Hi David, I'll check and testing this program that you recommended. Thanks.

Comment: @Delphi - You don't need to access the menu to launch the windows that the menu items launch if you can figure out the command ids of the items, then you can probably send a wm_command message.